# Creating custom Metric Classes in Tensorflow Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I would like to build a metric, to calculate precision on a group level.

E.g. assuming an LSTM output of shape `(batch, 10, 1)`, I would like to group along the temporal dimension (group by the 10 timestamps) and calculate precision.

I created the metric, which inherits precision as so:

```
class PrecisionGrouped(tf.keras.metrics.Precision):
  def __init__(self,
               thresholds=None,
               top_k=None,
               class_id=None,
               name=None,
               dtype=None):
    super(PrecisionGrouped, self).__init__(name=name, dtype=dtype)

  def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    y_true = tf.math.reduce_max(y_true, axis=1)
    y_pred = tf.math.reduce_max(y_pred, axis=1)
    return super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
```

However, when I run the code, it complains that the update_state method should return a tensor. 
But I'm simply calling the method of the parent, which also returns the `update_op`.

```
TypeError: To be compatible with tf.contrib.eager.defun, Python functions must return zero or more Tensors; in compilation of <function PrecisionGrouped.update_state at 0x1a384b1400>, found return value of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Operation'>, which is not a Tensor.
```

All I am doing is adding a simple preprocessing step to the input. `tf.keras.metrics.Precision()` works as expected, but not `PrecisionGrouped()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove return from `update_state()` method.

```
def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    y_true = tf.math.reduce_max(y_true, axis=1)
    y_pred = tf.math.reduce_max(y_pred, axis=1)
    super().update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
```

> You can remove return statements and group ops from custom metrics. It is not required. Built in metrics have a different requirement because of an issue with TPUs. Once that is fixed we will remove the return from update_state from built-in metrics as well.

Please refer this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30711) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. The only thing I added is `sample_weight=1`, since it has to be broadcastable to `y_true`.